# A simple doubt on classical mechanics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science

**Question:**

> "At a certain instant of time, the mass of a rocket going up vertically is $100 kg$. If it is ejecting $5 kg$ of gas per second at a speed of $400 m/s$, the acceleration of the rocket would be? (assume $g=10m/s^2$)"

**My attempt:**
Considering only two forces on the rocket; Thrust(along $+y$ axis) and Weight ($-y$) axis.

Calculating weight;
$$\vec{W}=1000\vec{(-j)}$$

Calculating thrust(assuming thrust to be constant):

$\vec{v}=$ velocity vector;
$m=$ instantaneous mass.
So,
$$\vec{T}=\frac{d \vec{(momentum)}}{dt}$$
$$\vec{T}=\vec{v} \frac{dm}{dt}  + m \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$

Since mass is being lost(ejected), and velocity is constant due to thrust force(I am not very confident regarding this argument that the velocity is constant),

$$\frac{dm}{dt}=-5,$$

$$\therefore\vec{T}=\vec{v}(-5) + 0 $$

$$\vec{T}=\vec{v}(-5)=?$$

I got lost from here. Rough work of what I did after this is-
$$\vec{T}=\vec{v}(-5)$$

$$\vec{T}=400\vec{j}(-5)$$

$$\vec{T}=2000\vec{(-j)} $$

This gives Thrust and Weight both downwards, which is obviously wrong.

Further calculation involves,
$$\text{Net acceleration}=\frac{\text{Thrust}_{\text{upwards}}-\text{Weight}_{\text{downwards}}}{\text{instantaneous mass}}$$.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

**P.S.**
Answer to above problem is:

> 10m/s^2

Comment: One possible approach may be, first calculating magnitude only for the forces involved and then using the proper vector for further calculation. Example; Thrust force has magnitude 2000N and is acting in +Y axis and Weight has magnitude 1000N and is acting -Y axis. But this still does not answer why the velocity due thrust became constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful with the rocket equation: you can *not* just use $$F=dp/dt$$ because that can lead to inconsistent results.

You need to use conservation of momentum to [derive the equation for the thrust](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/599655/is-there-a-derivation-for-the-thrust-formula/599660#599660) (assume there is no gravity in the simple case) and get

$$|T|=|c{dm\over dt}|$$

where $c$ is the relative velocity. With this computation you get that the thrust points in the direction of the rocket motion - of course - and that formula gives you the *magnitude* of the thrust $T$. See the linked answer for full derivation and sign convention - the same force $T$ actually pushes in both direction (the rocket and the expelled stuff), so you can choose which one you consider.

In thise case, $c=400m/s$ (I assume, although poor phrasing of the problem, that the speed the problem refers to is the velocity at which the gas is ejected) and $dm/dt=-5$ so that

$T = | (400 m/s)*(- 5 Kg/s) | = 2000 Kg m/s^2 = 2000 N$ pointing upwards.

The reason you can not simply use $dp/dt$ is that $v$ (in this answer calld $c$) is not the rocket velocity but the relative one. Careful with that, use directly the thrust equation remembering that it points upwards and that it used the *relative* speed.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you answer by thinking it through in smaller chunks.

Start by switching gravity off and getting your head around that, then bring gravity back in once you have understood how rocket thrust works. To understand the basic idea, use conservation of momentum: the $m v$ of rocket before ejecting a little fuel must be equal to total momentum of rocket and fuel after a little fuel was ejected. The rocket then has mass $(m - \delta m)$, upwards speed $v + \delta v$ and the ejected fuel has mass $\delta m$, and upwards speed somewhere between $v - w$ and $v + \delta v - w$, where $w$ is the relative speed of rocket and ejected matter (here 400 m/s). Now write down conservation of momentum (it's best if I don't do it for you) and finally think carefully about that $\delta m$. The $\delta m$ is positive as I have defined it, but the mass of the rocket is going down. So the relationship between rocket mass $m(t)$ and the $\delta m$ appearing in the momentum formulae is
$$
\frac{dm}{dt} = \lim_{\delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{-\delta m}{\delta t}
$$
That is, the $\delta m$ I used was not the mass increase of the rocket but the mass decrease.

In the equations some terms cancel, and there is a second-order term involving $\delta v \delta m$ which can be neglected in comparison to the first-order terms in the limit of small quantities.

One can also present the same reasoning in terms of $dm$ but then the mass of the ejected fuel is $-dm$ which can seem counter-intuitive. Either way one has this awkward sign and you just need to handle it as seems clearest to you.

By the above method you should be able to arrive at the standard rocket thrust equation. But you can only learn this by arriving at it by your own process of reasoning.